# How do I go about creating a TagBlock that I can use in a StructBlock and not in a page

Tags: django-taggit, wagtail

Something like this where the field `emails` is a `django-taggit` field which queries the email model and suggests emails.

```
class MailingList(blocks.StructBlock):
    """
    A collection of emails
    """

    name = blocks.CharBlock(max_length=255)
    emails = TagBlock()
```

Will subclassing the `blocks.CharBlock` with a custom widget help ?

I tried something like this with no luck

```
from taggit.forms import TagField, TagWidget

class TagBlock(blocks.CharBlock):
    widget = TagWidget
    def __init__(self, required=True, help_text=None, max_length=None, min_length=None, **kwargs):
        self.field = TagField(
            required=required,
            help_text=help_text,
            max_length=max_length,
            min_length=min_length,
            widget=TagWidget
        )
        super(TagBlock, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```